# How to numerically evaluate results of an unet-like CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, evaluation

I am looking for a way to numerically evaluate the results of my unet-like CNN.

The CNN is trained to remove artifacts from grayscale images. Therefore the CNN gets a "9 channel" grayscale image containing artifacts in each channel (9 grayscale images with partially redundant data but different artifacts are concatenated --> dimensions[numTrainInputs, 512, 512, 9]) as input and should output a single grayscale image without artifacts [numTrainInputs, 512, 512, 1]. The CNN is trained using MSE as loss function and Adam as Optimizer and Keras. So far, so good.

Visually the CNN provides good results when compared to an artifact free "ground truth" image --> dimensions[numTrainInputs, 512, 512, 1] but the accuracy during training remains at 0%. I think this is because none of the result images perfectly fits to the ground truth, right!?

But how can I numerically evaluate the results? I searched for some numerical evaluations in the field of autoencoders but coulnd't find a proper way. Can someone give me a hint?

The CNN looks like this:

```
input_1 = Input((X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]))

conv1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(input_1)
conv2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(conv2)
conv4 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(conv3)
conv5 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(conv4)
conv6 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(conv5)

upconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(conv6)
upconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(upconv1)
upconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(upconv2)
upconv3_1 = concatenate([upconv3, conv4], axis=3)

upconv4 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(upconv3_1)
upconv4_1 = concatenate([upconv4, conv3], axis=3)

upconv5 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(upconv4_1)
upconv5_1 = concatenate([upconv5,conv2], axis=3)

upconv6 = Conv2DTranspose(8, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='elu',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(upconv5_1)
upconv6_1 = concatenate([upconv6,conv1], axis=3)

upconv7 = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='linear',  use_bias=True, padding='same')(upconv6_1)

model = Model(outputs=upconv7, inputs=input_1)



model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=100, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.01, callbacks=[tbCallback])
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong metrics for this problem.
In regression 'accuracy' as metric makes no sense.
Change it to MSE for example:

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error']))
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use MSE as loss function and also as error metric? Isn't it saying the same thing twice?

Comment: In regression this is fine. If you want a different measure you could try SSIM to further evalute how similar is the filtered to the noiseless image.